# Rails - Nested association - scope order - with I18n translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, join, scope, rails-i18n, globalize

I am using globalize and i18n.
I have the following models:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    ...
    scope :sort_with_teaser, lambda { |direction|
        joins(test: :test_translations).
            where(test_translations: {locale: 'fr'}).
            order("test_translations.teaser #{ direction }")        
        }
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    translates :teaser
    ...
end
```

So with Globalize and I18n, I have also a test_translations table.

I want to implement a scope sort_with_teaser inside my Result model to sort result with their result.test.teaser. But I this code doesn't work.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just fixed it :

```
joins(test: :translations).where(test_translations: {locale: 'fr'}).order("test_translations.teaser #{ direction }")
```